# pip install airflow not working for version 1.7.1.3

Tags: python, pip, airflow, pypi

We have been using airflow in our prod environments since last 2 years and are on 1.7.1.3 version.

Lately, when I tried to do **pip install airflow==1.7.3.1**, it failed to install and verbose log helped in tracing the artifact location - https://pypi.org/simple/apache-airflow/

I see that 1.7.1.3 version of airflow is removed from there.

Is there any other repository which hosts the artifact? If no, which other alternative do I have to have it installed using pip?

Comment: If you're lucky, you may still have a wheel in cache on a machine where you installed `airflow` before: `find ~/.cache/pip -name apache-airflow*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `pip` name for Airflow is now `apache-airflow`, as for the version, the 1.7.1.3 tag is [still available from the Github repository](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/1.7.1.3). To install it you'll need to clone the repository, checkout the specific tag, and then do a `pip install` against the repository folder:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git
Cloning into 'incubator-airflow'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Total 40506 (delta 3), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 40497
Receiving objects: 100% (40506/40506), 27.82 MiB | 1.75 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (29080/29080), done.
$ cd incubator-airflow
$ git checkout tags/1.7.1.3
Note: checking out 'tags/1.7.1.3'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 209bf9c7... Adding .readthedocs.yml to build docs for 1.7.1.3
$ pip install .
```

Comment: One can also ``wget https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/archive/1.7.1.3.tar.gz && tar -xzf 1.7.1.3.tar.gz && cd airflow-1.7.1.3 && pip install .`` to omit Git

Comment: @Rolf, your comment can be an answer on its own.